# How to make child div to be 100% height of position absolute parent container

Tags: html, css

How to make child div to be 100% height of position absolute fixed parent container?

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An idea is to make the parent element flex container so the child element will be stretched by default:

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8r9waygg/)

You just add a 100% height to your child `div`. To show that it really works, I changed the top and bottom of the parent div so that you can see that the child is 100% of its parent.

```
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 0;
  background: steelblue;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: In some conditions this will not work un-till you will not give the position relative to child.

Comment: @Atul and what are these condition ?

Comment: @Atul I tried giving the child a position of absolute and it still works, what conditions do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use 100% height with child div, Like

```
.Child{
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add a height of `100%`.

```css
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative:

Use `position: relative` on parent and `height: 100%` on child

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;  
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;  
}
```

Here is a [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/giorgosk/pen/jOMEpvy)

Answer (score -2):

you should give 100vh height to child div like

```
.child{
 height:100vh;
}
```